# Using div.column in jade

Tags: angularjs, pug

What is the below code for?

I am new to jade. The below is a code i am stuck with.

```
extends layouts/default

block content
  div.column(ui-auth-directive)
```

Here extends is going to extend default.jade, then to that, it is going to append the div tag.

But I dont understand what does this div.column mean? and what is this ui-auth-directive mean?

Upto my understanding, div.abcd means that abcd is a class.. Could some one please help me in this regard.

Thanks,
Sabarisri

Comment: Could you pls format your jade code?

Comment: You can test what it's turned in to [here](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div.column(ui-auth-directive)` will compile to:

```
<div class="column" ui-auth-directive></div>
```

Understanding what the directive does is up to you and your code.  It will be defined by your angular module.